# Efficiently getting the sum from a query

Tags: plsql

I'm having the table EQUIP where it contains 10M+ rows.Though the query executes within few seconds, it takes hours to run the for loop. I feel its very inefficient. It basically takes the sum of rows which matches the given condition. Please kindly give me an efficient approach to run this. I created the index for EXIPMNT(mch_code,contract,CRE_DATE)

I need to get sum of each M,P,T,X,E,D separately

```
CURSOR get_cost_ IS
  SELECT EQUIP, COST
  FROM   EXIPMNT
  WHERE  mch_code = mch_code_
  AND contract = contract_
  AND CRE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR;

BEGIN

FOR rec_ IN get_cost_ LOOP
  IF (rec_. EQUIP = 'M') THEN
     material_ := material_ + nvl(rec_.cost, 0);
  ELSIF (rec_. EQUIP = 'P') THEN
     personal_ := personal_ + nvl(rec_.cost, 0);
  ELSIF (rec_. EQUIP = 'T') THEN
     tool_facility_ := tool_facility_ + nvl(rec_.cost, 0);
  ELSIF (rec_. EQUIP = 'X') THEN
     expense_ := expense_ + nvl(rec_.cost, 0);
  ELSIF (rec_. EQUIP = 'E') THEN
     external_ := external_ + nvl(rec_.cost, 0);
  ELSIF (rec_. EQUIP = 'D') THEN
     direct_sales_ := direct_sales_ + nvl(rec_.cost, 0);
  END IF; 

 NULL;
 END LOOP;

   total_cost_ := material_ + personal_ + tool_facility_ + expense_ + external_     + direct_sales_;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're literally just after the sum of all the rows with the specified values, then this should do the trick:

```
select sum(cost)
from   exipmnt
where  mch_code = mch_code_
and    contract = contract_
and    cre_date >= TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
and    cre_date < TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
and    equip in ('M', 'P', 'T', 'X', 'E', 'D');
```

Otherwise here are some other ways you might be looking for:

Display the total for each equip value in separate rows (with a third column displaying the full total across all rows:

```
select equip,
       sum(cost),
       sum(sum(cost)) over () total_cost
from   exipmnt
where  mch_code = mch_code_
and    contract = contract_
and    cre_date >= TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
and    cre_date < TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
and    equip in ('M', 'P', 'T', 'X', 'E', 'D')
group by equip;
```

Pivoting the rows into columns pre 11g style:

```
select sum(case when equip = 'M' then cost end) material_total,
       sum(case when equip = 'P' then cost end) personal_total,
       sum(case when equip = 'T' then cost end) tool_facility_total,
       sum(case when equip = 'X' then cost end) expense_total,
       sum(case when equip = 'E' then cost end) external_total,
       sum(case when equip = 'D' then cost end) direct_sales_total,
       sum(cost) total
from   exipmnt
where  mch_code = mch_code_
and    contract = contract_
and    cre_date >= TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
and    cre_date < TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
and    equip in ('M', 'P', 'T', 'X', 'E', 'D');
```

Pivoting the rows 11g style:

```
select material_total,
       personal_total,
       tool_facility_total,
       expense_total,
       external_total,
       direct_sales_total,
       nvl(material_total, 0)
         + nvl(personal_total, 0)
         + nvl(tool_facility_total, 0)
         + nvl(expense_total, 0)
         + nvl(external_total, 0)
         + nvl(direct_sales_total, 0) total
from   (select *
        from   exipmnt
        where  mch_code = mch_code_
        and    contract = contract_
        and    cre_date >= TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        and    cre_date < TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
        and    equip in ('M', 'P', 'T', 'X', 'E', 'D'))
pivot (sum(cost) as total for equip in ('M' as material,
                                        'P' as personal,
                                        'T' as tool_facility,
                                        'X' as expense,
                                        'E' as external,
                                        'D' as direct_sales));
```

Comment: I've given you 3 ways to do that.

Comment: Got it... Is there away where I can get the answer quickly within seconds by creating indexes

Comment: If you had an index on (mch_code, contract, cre_date, equip and cost), that might help.

Comment: Hi Boneist, I have a little doubt,,,, When the appropriate index is provided it seems that the approach given by me and you gives the same time.  What I need to know is, in executing wise, does the Pivoting the rows into columns pre 11g style: which was given by you and what I had done has any differences?

Comment: You'd have to check the execution plan to see what the query I provided is doing. You might also be able to check [Real Time SQL Monitoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/real-time-sql-monitoring-11gr1)